# How to insert the ClientID of a div into an OnClientClick event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-controls, clientid

In the XHTML for a page I have:-

```
<asp:Button ID="bookNowButton" runat="server" CssClass="bookNowButton"
            OnClientClick="showHideLoggedInDiv('<%=bookingFormDiv.ClientID%>')" />
```

This breaks.  I need the correct syntax or method to insert the bookingFormDiv.ClientID into the control.

What needs to be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the attribute from code behind:

```
bookNowButton.OnClientClick = "showHideLoggedInDiv('" + bookingFormDiv.ClientID + "')"
```

Comment: That worked nicely thanks.  Unfortunately it causes a form post. How do I stop it?  I should explain I'm changing an html <input /> tag into an <asp:Button></Button> tag.  All the button does is open and close a Div. I don't want it to do anything else.

Thanks

Comment: @Craig That's the default behavior of the button. You can return `false` from the OnClientClick to prevent that. There might also be a property along the lines of `CausesPostback` on the button, but I'm too lazy to look.

Comment: Thanks for that. It led me to set UseSubmitBehavior = "False". So all done;)

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

As this is the correct syntax i would start looking elsewhere, what is bookingFormDiv, is it  server side control (runat=server) with the id bookingFormDiv?

edit

realised this is within a server side control (asp:Button) so you cannot use that syntax, the accepted answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `runat="server"`, then replace `asp:Button` with `input type="button"` and `OnClientClick` with `onclick`.